# shiny::reactlogShow displays error, when running by batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, shiny, rselenium

**Setting:**
I have one Shiny-App (`app.r`) from which I want a [reactive graph](https://mastering-shiny.org/reactive-graph.html) of all reactive elements. In my understanding, one must trigger these elements once before they are shown in the graph. Therefore, I created a `Start_App.r` which runs the app and records reactive elements and a `Navigate_through_App.r`-Script which navigates via RSelenium through the App. Because R is busy when running a shiny app, both scripts need to run in different R Sessions. Starting them 'by hand' results in the required reactive graph:

[image]

In order to automate the process of starting two R Sessions and executing the scripts, I created a simple Batch-file called `Start.bat`. It starts the shiny app, the RSelenium browser and navigates through the app as intended.

---

**Problem:**
When I run the batch-script, ***the files recorded by the reactlog-command can't be found*** on my machine:

[image]

It looks like there was a try to create this file (because there is this explicit path), but somehow it does not worked. Any ideas what could cause this problem?

---

**Code:**
(All files in the same folder)

app.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "shinyjs.closeWindow = function() { window.close(); }"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("closeWindow")),
  actionButton("close", "Close window")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$close, {
    js$closeWindow()
    stopApp()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Start_App.r

```
#Install & load packages
  if (!require("shiny")) install.packages("shiny")
    library(shiny)
  if (!require("reactlog")) install.packages("reactlog")
    library(reactlog)
  
#tell shiny to log reactivity
  #reactlog::reactlog_enable()
  options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE)

#run App
  runApp(getwd(), host = getOption("shiny.host", "127.0.0.1"), port=7777, launch.browser = TRUE)

#once app has closed, display reactlog from shiny
  shiny::reactlogShow()
```

Navigate_through_App.r:

```
#Install & load packages
  if (!require("RSelenium")) install.packages("RSelenium")
  library(RSelenium)

#free all ports
  system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
  
#Start Selenium and access shiny-app
  rD <- rsDriver(port = 4564L, browser = "firefox") # "chrome" / "firefox" is possible
  #Assign the client to an object 
    remDr <- rD[["client"]]
  #Open Shiny-App
    remDr$navigate("http://127.0.0.1:7777")
    
  #Stop App
    #Click button "App beenden & Browser schließen"
      webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="close"]')
      webElem$clickElement()
```

Start.bat:

```
START /HIGH R -e "source('Start_App.r')" 
Rscript Navigate_through_App.r
pause
```